# How to move & rotate the marker smoothly depends on its moving direction

Tags: react-google-maps-api

In the GoogleMapMarker component, I have developed with MarkerClusterer component in '@react-google-map/api'.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Marker, MarkerClusterer } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Geocode from 'react-geocode';
import carIcon from '../../../app/images/car.png';
import bikeIcon from '../../../app/images/bikeResized.png';

//Geocode API Key
Geocode.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY);

const GoogleMapMarker = () => {
  let { markers = [] } = useSelector(state => state.reducers);
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState({ prev: [], current: [] });

  // calculate the angle between previous and new positions
  const calculateRotationAngle = (id, newLat, newLng) => {
    if (loc?.current?.length > 0 && loc.prev?.length > 0) {
      let { lat, lng } = loc.prev.find(mar => mar.id === id);
      const angle = Math.atan2(newLng - lng, newLat - lat) * (180 / Math.PI);
      return angle;
    }
    return 90;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoc({ prev: loc.current, current: markers });
  }, [markers]);

  return (
    <MarkerClusterer
      averageCenter
      enableRetinaIcons
      gridSize={60}
      defaultImageSizes={[10, 10]}
    >
      {clusterer =>
        markers?.length > 0 &&
        markers?.map(item => {
          let { id, lat, lng, info, deviceType } = item;
          let title = info[0]?.split(' ')?.pop();
          return (
            <Marker
              key={id}
              position={{ lat, lng }}
              title={title}
              clusterer={clusterer}
              icon={{
                url: deviceType === 'bike' ? bikeIcon : carIcon,
                scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(40, 40),
                rotation: calculateRotationAngle(id, lat, lng)
              }}
              animation={window.google.maps.Animation.DROP}
            />
          );
        })
      }
    </MarkerClusterer>
  );
};

export default GoogleMapMarker;
```

In this component, the marker didn't rotate according to its moving direction.

I have tried with,

```
icon={{path: 'M29.395,0H17.636c-3.117,0-5.643,3.467-5.643,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759   c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644V6.584C35.037,3.467,32.511,0,29.395,0z M34.05,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L34.05,14.188z    M32.618,10.773c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H16.631l-2.222-8.51C14.41,10.773,23.293,7.755,32.618,10.773z M15.741,21.713   v4.492l-2.73-0.349V14.502L15.741,21.713z M13.011,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L13.011,37.938z M14.568,40.882l2.218-3.336   h13.771l2.219,3.336H14.568z M31.321,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L31.321,35.805',rotation: calculateRotationAngle(id, lat, lng)}}
```

It works perfectly but without any moving animation. I can't get SVG path for motorcyle, truck & other vehicle types.

So what should I do ..?